# How to calculate years left in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

This is the function I used and it work `=YEAR(A1)-YEAR(B1)`, A1 is today B1 is the date in the future or past. The problem is that I want to round up year and months.

This is the exaple: https://i.stack.imgur.com/camkR.jpg .

The answer that I am looking for is 2.2(2 years and 2 months). 
I think the problem is with the formatting.

Comment: Welcome. Please share a brief description of your search/research efforts, your attempts to figure out the solution by yourself and a specific description of where did you get stuck. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Hint: familiarise yourself with the YEAR function.

Comment: @MartinKitukov Please explain how you get 2.2 from your example? I get the "two years" but both dates are in the month of July, and within the month, they are within 2 days of each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula

```
=(year(B3)-year(C3))+(round((month(B3)-month(C3))/12,1))
```

The logic is:
1 - Calculate the difference in years.
2 - Calculate the difference in months, then divide by 12 (round to one decimal).
3 - Add the years and months together.

This works with dates >12 months, as well as dates <12 months, and even dates within the same year.

---

[image: Sampla calculations]

---

This screenshot shows the result of decimalisation of months.
[image: Decimalisation of months]